# Compability problems with jssor in different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

The following code works in Firefox but not in IE and Chrome. How can I modify it so that it's compatible with all the browsers?

```
Jaquery(document).ready function($){
Var _sildeshowTransitions = [
{$ Duration:1500, x:0.5, $cols:2, $Rotate:0.5, $ChessMode:{ $ Column:3},$Easing:{$left: $jssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic},$opacity:2,$SlideOut:true,}
];
```

Thanks for your site, thanks for your answers.

Comment: post your code and screenshots, a description of the bug and the desired solution. We have absolutely nothing to go on here to help you at this point.

Comment: Please answer to my question

Comment: Your question is not clear.I modify it so that it sounds better. Double check and see if it is correct now.